# What is weighted prediction in video encoding and how is it used?

Tags: video, video-processing

I'm relatively a new to video processing. I have to do a project on weighted prediction. However, there is no sufficient documentation on internet as to what exactly is weighted prediction and how weighted prediction is done. It would be great if someone can help me on this or point to the related sources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question, but it's too broad to be on-topic on other StackExchange sites either.

Comment: you are on the wrong forum. When you scroll down there are a lot of other sites that could help you in this case. StackOverflow is not a generic help forum. Its more for programming problems. Take a look at this http://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts

Answer (score 1):

Video codecs include a number of techniques (called tools) used to efficiently compress a motion video signal. Weighted prediction is a tool included in MPEG-4 AVC and also in HEVC to solve a particular corner case. Ordinarily, a fade out to black (or fade in from black) would be difficult for an encoder to handle efficiently since the frame to frame prediction error is high for many consecutive frames. The weighted prediction technique uses a multiplicative weighting factor and an additive offset which are applied to the motion compensated prediction to avoid this and thus improves the coding efficiency during fades. Hope that helps.